# How to write out an Array to file in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a DataFrame `df` that looks like:

```
+--------------------+
|            features|
+--------------------+
|[9.409448, 0.0, 0.3]|
|[9.055118, 2.0, 0.3]|
|[9.055118, 2.9, 0.2]|
+--------------------+
```

It has 1 column called "features", which is an array of floats.

How would I write it out to a csv file that looks like this?

```
9.409448, 0.0, 0.3
9.055118, 2.0, 0.3
9.055118, 2.9, 0.2
```

What I tried:

- Write the dataframe with DataFrameWriter - but it complains that writing as a csv can't handle arrays.
- posexplode and pivot so the DataFrame has 3 columns, one for each number. But this feels very inefficient, especially when I have more columns.

Idea: Maybe convert this to a Matrix somehow? I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You can’t write arrays to csv as arrays are objects and csv does not handle objects. You need to convert array to string and then try to write

Comment: You can try to iterate over the rows in the feature column. You can write arrays to a csv file by modifying the best answer at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72458/export-list-of-values-into-csv-or-txt-file

Comment: I would like to use the exporter native to Spark so it writes files to partitions / can be scaled across multiple machines. Writing a custom file writer seems very difficult...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your schema is something like:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- features: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
```

One idea is to cast your array of floats into an array of strings. Then you can call [`pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.concat_ws) to extract the elements from inside the array (now strings) into one string.

For example, using `", "` as the seperator:

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df = df.select(
    f.concat_ws(", ", f.col("features").cast("array<string>")).alias("features")
)
df.show(truncate=False)
#+------------------+
#|features          |
#+------------------+
#|9.409448, 0.0, 0.3|
#|9.055118, 2.0, 0.3|
#|9.055118, 2.9, 0.2|
#+------------------+
```

As you can see from the schema, you now just have a string in the `features` column:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- features: string (nullable = false)
```

---

**Update**

When writing to a csv using [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv), the default behavior is to quote values if the separator appears as part of the value. To turn off quoting, set the `quote` option to empty string when you write the file.

Comment: Unfortunately when you write this file out as a csv, it would write these annoying quotes " to the beginning and end of lines...eg. "9.409448, 0.0, 0.3"\n"9.055118, 2.0, 0.3" and so on

Comment: @foobar just set the `quote` argument to an empty string in [`pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv) to turn off quoting.

Comment: this prints all array elements in one column. I'd imagine that OP (as in my case) wants each number (feature value) to go into it's own column. For one csv there MAY be a way to manually do that in excel, but for many csvs this just doesn't work. What's needed is a Pandas style ".apply(panda.Series)" to that column